# Bokeh: How to Add Vertical Lines that Connect Dots

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, bokeh

I have 2 columns, sharing the same x-axis values, that I want to connect using vertical lines. This is the desired effect:

[image]

I was able to implement it in matplotlib:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
         ax.plot([row['x']]*2, row[['y1', 'y2']], color='grey', lw=1, zorder=0, alpha=0.5)
```

How can I achieve this in Bokeh?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0, 5, (10, 2)), columns=['x','y'])
df_2 = df.copy()
df_2['y'] = df_2['y'] - 5
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
source_2 = ColumnDataSource(df_2)
myplot = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=400, tools='hover,box_zoom,box_select,crosshair,reset')
myplot.circle('x', 'y', size=7, fill_alpha=0.5, source=source)
myplot.circle('x', 'y', size=7, fill_alpha=0.5, color='orange', source=source_2)
show(myplot, notebook_handle=True);
```

Bokeh code result:

[image]

Underlying data example: Y2 will always be larger than Y1.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [`segment`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#segments-and-rays) glyph method:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

x  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y1 = [6, 7, 2, 4, 5]
y2 = [10, 12, 11, 14, 13]

p = figure(plot_height=350)

p.segment(x, y1, x, y2, color="lightgrey", line_width=3)
p.circle(x, y1, color="blue", size=20)
p.circle(x, y2, color="red", size=20)

show(p)
```

[image]

This code passes the data directly to the glyph methods, but it would also be sensible to put everything in one `ColumnDataSource` that gets shared for all the glyphs.